# Controlling a Roku TV through a Google Assistant Action

Tags: actions-on-google

Here’s the scenario. Each Roku device advertises itself on the local network and exposes a protocol on the network of controlling the device. I know that the Assistant actions can make calls to a known address but is it possible to create an action that can query and interact with the local network?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, Actions cannot make calls directly to a local network, only publicly accessible https urls.

As a longer answer, you could set up an intermediary device like a Raspberry Pi that has a web server and also is able to do local network calls.